# Want to get data out of Parse getCallback in Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, callback, android-parsequeryadapter

I'm using Parse.com, and to get my wanted information, I use it's Queries.

So I use that one:

```
ParseUser PhotoeUser;

ParseQuery<Photo> UserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Photo.class);
        UserQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", PhotoID);
        UserQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Photo>() {
            @Override
            public void done(Photo pPhoto, ParseException error) {
                PhotoUser = pPhoto.getUser();
            }
        });
```

So what I want is simply use the `PhotoUser` outside of that query. But When I write:

```
Log.i("Profile", "PhotoUser = " + PhotoUser.get("objectId"));
```

`PhotoUser.get("objectId")` is `null`.

Another example is this one:

```
public ParseUser getUser(){
ParseQuery<Photo> UserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Photo.class);
        UserQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", PhotoID);
        UserQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Photo>() {
            @Override
            public void done(Photo pPhoto, ParseException error) {
                PhotoUser = pPhoto.getUser();
            }
        });

return PhotoUser;
}
```

Here, when I want to return the `PhotoUser`, it is `null`.

Please help me. If you need more information, just ask for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take ParseUser outside the block:

```
PhotoUser pUser;
ParseQuery<Photo> UserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Photo.class);
    UserQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", PhotoID);
    UserQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Photo>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Photo pPhoto, ParseException error) {
            pUser = pPhoto.getUser();
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to give variables names. I don't know how do You want to get `PhotoUser` when You query for `Photo`.

Comment: PhotoUser is already named at the beginning, I edited my code above so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method

```
public ParseUser getUser(){
 ParseQuery<Photo> UserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Photo.class);
 UserQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", PhotoID);
 UserQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Photo>() {
   @Override
   public void done(Photo pPhoto, ParseException error) {
    PhotoUser = pPhoto.getUser();
   }
 });

return PhotoUser;
}
```

returns `null` because is simply is when you are returning it. You are creating a background task that sets `PhotoUser` when it finishes, but instantly after creating the task you return your current reference to `PhotoUser`. The task finishes a little time later and sets your `PhotoUser`. So either you don't return anything and call some method when task finishes or you use `ParseQuery.get()` which blocks until it has found the object.

Also, please name you member variables with a small letter at the start. (`userQuery` and `photoUser`).

Edit:
As requested, change your code to:

```
public ParseUser getUser(){
 ParseQuery<Photo> UserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Photo.class);
 UserQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", PhotoID);
 PhotoUser = UserQuery.getFirst().getUser();
 return PhotoUser;
}
```

or

```
public void getUser(){
 ParseQuery<Photo> UserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Photo.class);
 UserQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", PhotoID);
 UserQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<Photo>() {
   @Override
   public void done(Photo pPhoto, ParseException error) {
    PhotoUser = pPhoto.getUser();
    doWork();
   }
 });
}

private void doWork() {
  // do what you want to do with your PhotoUser, it is not null now
}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly with ParseQuery.get()? Can you please adopt it to my code? Thanks! :)

Comment: Just put `return PhotoUser` inside `done` because query goes in background and program goes on with next methods.

Comment: This won't work, the method wouldn't return anything and runtime.                                                                                                        As requested I updated my comment.